# Using vars_files with an include in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook I want to convert into a template, and include it using `include` elsewhere, and override a few variables, like this:

```
$ cat env_demo.yml
---
- include: template_standalone.yml
  vars:
    hosts: demo.example.com
    environment_name: "Demo environment"
```

This works fine, but then I'd like to encrypt some of the variables, like this:

```
$ cat env_demo_secret.yml
---
- include: template_standalone.yml
  vars:
    hosts: demo.example.com
  vars_files:
    - secrets/demo.example.com.yml
```

Now I get this error:

```
ERROR! 'vars_files' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude
```

My `template_standalone.yml` contains a list of different roles...:

```
$ cat template_standalone.yml
---
- name: Setting up standalone environment
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  roles:
   - role: php7   
   - role: nginx
   ...
```

...that need configuration like server passwords, etc., which I'd rather not have in plaintext in the main file. Any thoughts on what I could do instead?

Answer (score 2):

`vars_files` is not supported for included playbooks (as of Ansible 2.3)

You may opt to use extra variables file:

```
ansible-playbook -e @secrets/demo.example.com.yml env_demo.yml
```

Or use group variables file for `all` group – place your encrypted file into `./group_vars/all/demo.example.com.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, the extra variables method works for me. I'll just add a comment saying you need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use is using a list for the `vars_files` value like this:

```
- hosts: foo
  vars_files:
    - [ "secrets/demo.example.com.yml", "/dev/null" ]
```

If the `secrets/demo.example.com.yml` file exists, it will be included.  Otherwise ansible will read `/dev/null`, get an EOF, and go on its merry way.  I've used that for defining SSL variables in a playbook that's used by both external environments (that have SSL set up) and development environments (which do not).  I'm using ansible 2.10 and it's working well for me.